# Free Space after merging Partitons on Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, command-line, partition

I have a 256GB SSD El Capitan (the last iteration of it) on MacBook 12" late 2016 Model.

Before I had it, someone made an aditional partition of 125GB which I've deleted using various methods here described (Terminal commands).

The good is now I have one partition. The bad is less storage is usable.

[image]
[image]

Of the 256GB Storage device, only ~125GB is available :
[image]

How can I "merge" that space to the main disk in order to have again full 256GB of storage?

[image]

Comment: To see where the free space is, you will have to execute the command `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`. This command will not change your disk. Edit your question and post the output from the command.

Comment: Done as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add free space to the `Apple_CoreStorage` partition, a significant amount of free space must resize immediately after the `Apple_Boot` partition. Based on the error message you posted, this appears to be not true. If the free space resides above the `Apple_CoreStorage` partition, then this space can not be added to the `Apple_CoreStorage` partition.

You can determine where the free space exists by entering the command given below.

```
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
```

This command can be entered while booted to El Capitan, because SIP under this version of OS X allows reading from `/dev/disk0`, but not writing.

From the table published in the Wikipedia article [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs), one can determine a type of partition based on the GUID. From the command `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` output, one can determine the partitions with indices 1, 2, and 3 are types `EFI System partition`, `Apple Core Storage Container`, and `Apple Boot partition`, respectively. The 30,617,650 sectors of free space can be converted to bytes by multiplying by 4096 bytes per sector, which is 125.4 GB. Since this free space is above the  `Apple_CoreStorage` partition, the space can not be merged into the `Apple_CoreStorage` partition.

Unless your are an expert, the safest solution is to backup your data to an external drive, erase the internal drive, reinstall OS X and restore your data from backup. One possible alternative is given below. This alternative has not been tested.

1. Boot to Big Sur recovery or from a Big Sur installer and enter the command below.

   ```
   diskutil addPartition disk0s1 JHFS+ NewVolume 0
   ```
2. Install El Capitan or newer to the new partition.
3. Copy you data to the new installation or use the Migration Assistant.
4. Erase to free space the old `Apple_CoreStorage` and `Apple_Boot` partitions.
5. Merge the free space into the new partition.

Comment: Done, I've posted the screenshot but it is totaly not understandible to me....

Comment: "Since this free space is above the  Apple_CoreStorage partition, the space can not be merged into the Apple_CoreStorage partition."  What does this mean? It cannot be converted into free memory...? It will always get stuck somewhere in Limbo?

Comment: If there is a unreversible method of gaining the whole memory back with formating the disk, I'm all in ;-)

Comment: Your question was how to merge the free space into your current OS X volume. The answer is you can not. If you wish to ask a new question regarding what to do next, I would suggest you do so.